# Fatal error: Call to a member function send() on a non-object

Tags: php, email, pear

I'm trying to use the PEAR Mail 1.3 (downloaded from the PEAR site) to enable a contact form on a client site. However, I keep getting: **Fatal error: Call to a member function send() on a non-object**

The line on which it's getting hung up is: `$mail = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $body);`

Saw other threads dealing with this issue but I didn't understand the answer(s). Something about returning the $mail object? I tried what I thought they were talking about but had no luck. Here is the script:

```
$host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$username = "someAddy@email.com";
$password = "myPassword";
$port = "465";
$recipients = "myAddy@gmail.com";

 $headers = array ('From' => $email,
   'To' => $recipients,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'port' => $port,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = new Mail;
 $mail = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Fatal error: Call to a member function send() on a non-object

Pretty much means exactly what it says.

`send()` was called on something that wasn't an object. Looking at the code; `send()` is method to be called on an object stored in the `$smtp` variable. PHP is telling you that it expected `$smtp` to be an object, but that it was actually something else, probably `NULL`.

If you look at the PEAR docs for PEAR Mail it'll tell you what `Mail::factory()` is supposed to return if everything worked OK (An object), and what it returns if it didn't (Possibly a `NULL`). So if you `var_dump($smtp); die;` what do you see?

I'd look at the PEAR docs really closely to see under what circumstances it *won't* return the expected object, then check your inputs to see if any of those are suspect with regard to what `Mail::factory()` expects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so tired I don't remember how I figured it out, but here's how I fixed it. In *Applications>Mamp>bin>php>php5.5.10>lib>php*, I added a directory called **Net** with both SMTP.php (Net_SMTP-1.7.1) and Socket.php (Net_Socket 1.0.14), which I downloaded from the PEAR website. Don't remember how I figured out I was missing them. Got a server error from Google, so I changed the port to 587 and it finally worked. Also had to fix the permissions of the files and directories. So, there it is.

Comment: `Net_SMTP` is an optional dependency for the `Mail` package, and you need to install it if you want to use `Mail` to send mails via SMTP.